# Why I can't use web/images folder into Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I use asset to generate my images like :

```
<img class="icon_link icon2" src="{{ asset('images/icons/home.png') }}"/>
```

But I don't know why it's doesn't work. Because when I change 'images' by 'aaa' and I copy the icons folders into 'aaa' folders, it's work.

I have the same problem with img folder.

My web folder

- web

  - images

    - icons

      - home.png
- aaa

  - icons

    - home.png

When I access `local.dev/aaa/icons/home.png` it's work but not

`local.dev/images/icons/home.png`

Any Idea ? (I uninstall and install Symfony, but same problem)

Comment: Your virtual host "local.dev" should be a path to the web/ directory, and not to the root directory of symfony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOLVED

In the security.yml, I have to add my folder name :

```
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|icons|fonts|js)/
        security: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a /icons folder, you should try to disable alias mod of your apache or comment only the good alias

```
# Alias /icons/ "/usr/share/apache2/icons/"
```

Bye.

Comment: I'm on Debian, I don't found alias. There are 0 in apache2.conf.

Comment: Same problem when I disable alias mode.